# Importing a .CSV file into Python to make scatterplots and histograms

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to import a .CSV file (converted from an Excel file) into Python so I would be able to make correlation/scatter plots and histograms.

How do I do that?

Comment: Ideally you need to show what you've tried/researched already. What have you looked at?

Answer (score 14):

While you can use the `csv` module if you need to work with a csv file line by line, the `pandas` and `matplotlib` modules provide a higher level interface for data analysis tasks.

data.csv

```
x,y
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,7
5,11
6,12
7,13
8,20
9,17
10,19
```

plots.py

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df  = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.plot()  # plots all columns against index
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y') # scatter plot
df.plot(kind='density')  # estimate density function
# df.plot(kind='hist')  # histogram
```

output

[image]

## How it Works

```
df  = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

[read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) reads the csv file into a [Pandas Dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

The dataframe plot method is a wrapper around matplotlib's plot and is [documented here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Notice that we can get different kind of plots by adjusting the `kind=` keyword parameter to `df.plot()`. Histograms are available, in a newer version of matplotlib than is installed here, with `kind='hist'`

Answer (score 2):

Python has built in support for csv files: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. There are several examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First `import csv`, then you can use this code to open your `csv` file.
With the line `for row in reader:` you can loop through the rows in your `csv` file and use your code do whatever you need to do.

```
import csv
with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        #do something
```