# Read csv file and plot in pyplot mplot3d

Tags: python-3.x, csv, mplot3d

I have a csv file with a grid of z values corresponding to `x` in `[1,2,3,4]` and `y` in `[1,2,3]` like this:

```
1.1,1.2,1.3
2.1,2.2,2.3
3.1,3.2,3.3
4.1,4.2,4.3
```

I want to make a 3D scatterplot using mplot3d. What is the right way to read the file and make a 3D plot?

Comment: Check this out: https://pythonprogramming.net/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-tutorial/...And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085531/importing-a-csv-file-into-python-to-make-scatterplots-and-histograms

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but if the CSV file's first column contains `x` coordinates, the second contains `y` coordinates, and the third `z` coordinates, it's actually quite easy.

Assuming that your CSV file looks like this (the titles are important):

**points.csv**

```
x,y,z <- titles
1.1,1.2,1.3
2.1,2.2,2.3
3.1,3.2,3.3
4.1,4.2,4.3
```

Now, you can read the file in one line with `pandas`:

```
points = pandas.read_csv('points.csv')
```

Accessing each column is easy too:

```
points['x'].values #get the x coordinates
```

So then you can use matplotlib to plot the points:

**Full code:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

points = pandas.read_csv('points.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = points['x'].values
y = points['y'].values
z = points['z'].values

#  x   y   z  
# 1.1,1.2,1.3
# 2.1,2.2,2.3
# 3.1,3.2,3.3
# 4.1,4.2,4.3

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image: matplotlib graph]

**Notes:**

[Run this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/ActualHatefulApplescript)

Check [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-tutorial/) out for more info on 3D plotting with matplotlib